# Multiple typos on "approve tag wiki edits" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, suggested-edits, spelling

On this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

- registerd should be registered
- sumbitting should be submitting

Comment: note ... anyone with 2k rep can correct the priv wikis on meta ... I will then update them and push to the rest of the sites.

Comment: There are several other typos on that page, but I keep getting a timeout when I try to submit my edits.

Comment: @mmyers confirmed on that issue, fixing ...

Comment: @mmyers ... go for it ... it is editable now

Answer (score 2):

This is completed, however we need more help

Feel free to edit the privs on meta if you think they need tlc (2000 rep needed) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

We then will push them to all other sites.

Comment: How often do you push? Someone [reported an incorrect description on English.SE](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/687/access-to-moderator-tools-privilege-description-inaccurate-no-longer-highest-l), but the [relevant privilege page on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) was corrected by Arjan on the 10th. Is it just on an as-needed basis?